# Is it possible to embed one app entirely in another app

Tags: android, ios, embed

Is it possible to embed one app entirely (that I don't own) in another app that I could develop?
(not the content .. to run it entirely, as a standard app, but inside of another app).
Talking about android / ios apps.

If it's possible, how?

Comment: Applications provide APIs, libraries, plugins, or some other mechanism if they want any sort of exposure into another application somehow. You can also launch another application from your application. But to just embed it, that seems shady.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm asking because it's shady :)

Comment: "What about copyrights?" would be off-topic here, as it's a legal question, not a programming question.  I've removed it from the question to prevent closing for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. The closest thing to that would be having the "second" app already installed and then launch it from inside your own app. Not really useful, am I right?

Comment: Thanks Mike. not just to launch it, to embed it entirely.